# How do I find all the modules used by a Perl script?

Tags: perl, deployment

I'm getting ready to try to deploy some code to multiple machines. As far as I know, using a `Makefile.pm` to track dependencies is the best way to ensure they are installed everywhere.  The problem I have is I'm not sure our `Makefile.pm` has been updated as this application has passed through a few different developers.

Is there any way to automatically parse through either my source or a few full runs of my program to determine exactly what versions of what modules my application is depending on?  On top of that, is there any way to filter it based on [CPAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN) packages? (So that I only depend on [Moose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moose_%28Perl%29) instead of every single module that comes with Moose.)

A third related question is, if you depend on a version of a module that is not the latest, what is the best way to have someone else install it? Should I start including entire localized Perl installations with my application?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just to be clear - you can not generically get a list of modules that the app depends on by code analysis alone. E.g. if your apps does `eval { require $module; $module->import() }`, where `$module` is passed via command line, then this can ONLY be detected by actually running the specific command line version with ALL the module values.

If you do wish to do this, you can figure out every module used by a combination of runs via:

1. `Devel::Cover`. Coverage reports would list 100% of modules used. But you don't get version #s.
2. Print `%INC` at **every single possible exit point** in the code as slu's answer said. This should probably be done in `END{}` block as well as `__DIE__` handler to cover all possible exit points, and even then may be not fully 100% covering in generic case if somewhere within the program your `__DIE__` handler gets overwritten.
3. `Devel::Modlist` (also mentioned by slu's answer) - the downside compared to `Devel::Cover` is that it does NOT seem to be able to aggregate a database across multiple sample runs like `Devel::Cover` does. On the plus side, it's purpose-built, so has a lot of very useful options (CPAN paths, versions).
4. Please note that the other module (`Module::ScanDeps`) does NOT seem to allow you to do runtime analysis based on arbitrary command line arguments (e.g. it seems at first glance to only allow you to execute the program with no arguments) and if that's true, is inferior to all the above 3 methods for any code that may possibly load modules dynamically.

Comment: NOTE: search.cpan.org is shutting down (Jun 25, 2018).  It should redirect to meta cpan.  [Devel::Cover](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/PJCJ/Devel-Cover-1.29/lib/Devel/Cover.pm)

Answer (score 7):

> [Module::ScanDeps](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::ScanDeps) - Recursively scan Perl code for dependencies

Does both static and runtime scanning.  Just modules, I don't know of any exact way of verifying what versions from what distributions.  You could get old packages from [BackPan](http://backpan.perl.org/), or just package your entire chain of local dependencies up with [PAR](http://par.perl.org/).

Comment: Please note that `Module::ScanDeps` does NOT seem to allow you to do runtime analysis based on arbitrary command line arguments (e.g. it seems at first glance to only allow you to execute the program with no arguments). This is based on my glancing at POD, not experience, so I could be wrong.

Comment: thanks, this was useful, i also found that many of the other modules mentioned were not updated recently some dating back 10+ years

Answer (score 2):

You could look at %INC, see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=681911 which also mentions [Devel::Modlist](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aModlist)

Comment: See my answer for caveats of using `%INC`, as well as the other 2 modules mentioned so far.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use Devel::TraceUse, which also shows a tree of the modules, so it's easy to guess where they are being loaded.